# How to show add to cart in luma mobile theme?

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

In `Luma theme` (**mobile version**), how can I show the "`add to cart`" button under the products ?

In desktop + tablet it's shown.

**Edit :**

version I'm working is from  `Magento 2.2.7`, if it matters.

Thanks.

Comment: in luma theme, add to cart button is show by default for mobile!

Comment: For some reason not in the install that I have! What was showing by default was the wishlist + compare button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help, it happenned that css rule was disabled (product-item-actions). Installed directly from magento site, which is very strange. It's working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is "Enable One Page Checkout" on or off?
Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's indeed enabled, tho it is using a custom checkout module. Found what was happening.